# jquery command not refreshing after making changes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a cart and the cart has remove item button, but the jQuery is not working to remove the item from the cart. Am I missing something basic here ?

I have given class `remove1` to the remove button image and using the following jQuery... even I am not getting the alert.

HTML:

```
<img src='remove.gif' class='remove1'>
```

JS:

```
$(".remove1").click(function(){
    alert("hii");
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Is the remove button dynamically added?

Comment: If it is: `.delegate()` is a proper way of making it possible.

Comment: Is you jquery inside documen.ready

Comment: Yes it is dynamically added but .delegate() is also not working

Comment: Update your jquery to latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").delegate('.remove1','click',function(){
              alert("hii");
              $(this).parent().remove();
              });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you buttons are being added dynamically try this (requires newer version of jQuery):

```
$(document).on("click",".remove1", function(){
    alert("hii");
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Other wise you will need to use delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".remove1").live('click', function(){
    alert("hii");
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```